# issue regarding installing ionic and start ionic in ubuntu 14.04- 64 bit

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic.I have ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit.I have issue in installing ionic in my system.I completely following instruction given at official site of ionic for installation.But i have following issue while run following command:
 $ ionic start myApp tabs

Error: Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'
at Function.Module.``_resolveFilename  (module.js:338:15)